# Action Script 3 URLstream only streaming at ~25Mbps in Windows but line speed (100Mbps) on other OSes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash

Any reason I'm only able to stream data under windows 7 and XP (FF, Chrome and IE)  at about 25Mbps while in Linux and OS X Lion, I'm hitting line speed rates of 100Mbps ?
This is my URLStream code.
I'm certain it's not my connection or server side since I'm able to telnet to the same URL / Port and recieve the same data at line speed (100Mbps) 
Am I missing something obvious here?

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.errors.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLStream;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.utils.*;

public class URLStreamExample extends Sprite {
    private var stream:URLStream;
private var bytes:ByteArray;

    public function URLStreamExample():void {
        stream = new URLStream();
        bytes = new ByteArray();

        var stream:NetStreamInfo = stream.info;
        if (stream) Alert.show( stream.dataBufferByteLength.toString() );

        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://xxxxxx.net:7890");
        request.requestHeaders.push(header);
        configureListeners(stream);
        try {
            stream.load(request);
        } catch (error:Error) {
            trace("Unable to load requested URL.");
        }
    }

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:EventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler,false,0,true);
        stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler,false,0,true);
    }


    private function progressHandler(e:Event):void {
        //trace("progressHandler: " + event);
        e.target.readBytes(bytes, 0, e.target.bytesAvailable);
        bytes.clear();
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: are you using a debug player?